# Анализ нескольких таблиц SQLite на предмет сравнения. Передача выборок в telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite, aiogram

Есть две таблицы - с покупателями и продавцами.

Первая - продавец (tabl_seller):

```
id   seller   product   price
1    Вася     чашка     15
2    Саша     тарелка   12
3    Витя     ложка     9
4    Антон    вилка     10
```

Вторая - покупатель (tabl_buyer):

```
id   buyer    product   price
1    Игорь    чашка     12
2    Толя     коробка   10
3    Наташа   чашка     20
4    Вера     вилка     8
```

Через telegram-bot в таблицы добавляются и покупатели и продавцы.
Алгоритм сравнивает записи в обеих таблицах. И если условия выполняются, то тому, кто добавляет запись в таблицу, приходит сообщение от бота, что товар, который он продает/покупает есть или нет в другой таблице.
*Например, когда Наташа из второй таблицы добавляет запись о том, что готова купить чашку за 20, то тут же получает уведомление от бота о том, что для нее имеется одна запись из первой таблицы (Вася готов продать чашку за 15).*
Или же ничего не сообщается, если нет совпадений. И по этому принципу далее.

Теперь вопрос. *Каким образом уведомить Васю о том, что **появилась** Наташа и она готова купить его чашку?* Запись ведь была сделана раньше. Т.е., если сейчас в таблицу продавцов добавится запись, например, `5    Вова     чашка     17`, то ему бот сразу же отправит, что есть Наташа, которая купит его чашку. Но Наташа знать не будет о том, что появился Вова. Снова тот же вопрос - *как уведомить Наташу о том, что **появилась запись** с Вовой?*

Бот отрабатывает корректно в обе стороны, но только на момент добавления новой записи в ту или иную таблицы. Но не знаю, как сделать анализ уже существующих записей.
Сейчас читаю о триггерах в SQLite. Но, как я понимаю - это немного не то. Они, опять таки, уведомляют в момент внесения записи. Это уже реализовано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну такс а в чем проблема в бд добавить айди юзера из телеграмма и в момент когда происходит добавление проверять все? То есть когда Вова подает свою заявку то происходит проверка по продуктам и потом по ценам если условия прошли то по айди Наташы пишем ей типа bot.send_message(text="tururururu", chat_id=natasha_id, user_id=natasha_id)